# Making recursive function in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I want to make a recursive function that sums the integers between two values. I'm doing:

```
 let rec sum_between x y = 
   if x>y then sum_between y x else
      if x=y then x else x + sum_between x+1 y ;;
```

But I get the error: This expression has type int -> int
       but an expression was expected of type int

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: need sum_between (x + 1) y

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian How about posting this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function application has high precedence in OCaml. You need to parenthesize an expression when it's an argument to a function.

Your code

```
sum_between x+1 y
```

is parsed like this:

```
(sum_between x) + (1 y)
```

You need parentheses:

```
sum_between (x + 1) y
```

(Same answer as Edgar Aroutiounian but more helpful detail I hope.)